# Do openssl CA certificates get updated with apt-get upgrade?

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority, openssl, ubuntu

I use Ubunut 18.04. I need to know if OpenSSL CA certificates that are in this file:

```
/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

get updated when I upgrade my system using: `apt-get upgrade`?

I have a program that uses OpenSSL and validates servers' certs using the CA certs in this path. I need to know if I can assume that my file has an updated CAs list if I upgraded using `apt-get upgrade`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The global trust store in /etc/ssl/certs/ is part of the [ca-certificates](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ca-certificates) package and receives regular updates as can be seen from [this Changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/c/ca-certificates/ca-certificates_20180409/changelog). These are normal updates which get installed by `apt-get upgrade`.

The specific file itself is not part of the package but is generated by [update-ca-certificates](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html). This command gets automatically called on updates of `ca-certificates` as needed to reflect the changes in the trust store.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. So the bottom line is, with `apt-get upgrade`, the file `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` gets updated. Right?

Comment: @user9371654: correct.